# Plasma desktop freezes, but machine remains operable

Tags: debian, kde, freeze, plasma

I've got a Debian 9.13 machine for running LinuxCNC, with KDE/Plasma desktop. Generally everything works well, but every now and again, the desktop will freeze. The mouse still moves the cursor, the screen still goes to sleep after the set time and can be woken up with keyboard input, I can ssh to it, and amazingly, LinuxCNC g-code interpretation continues and the CNC machine keeps working.

But I can't move or activate windows, or do anything else. It forces me to restart the machine, which means losing positioning reference on the CNC machine.

Is there any way to recover this without having to re-launch LinuxCNC? Better still, is there any way to diagnose and fix the issue?

Comment: I habe a very similar behaivior with my kubuntu 22.10 (plasma 5.25.5) it freezes now and then when i am a little ti fast with Windows switching it seems.. (Alt+tab)